# Anaconda navigator IDE not launching

Tags: anaconda, conda, navigator

"conda is not recognized as an internal or external command". I have installed anaconda but none of the commands work. Also the navigator IDE and start menu option do not display. How to activate it? Pls help....earlier it was working. However n update it stopped. After that i installed and uninstalled anaconda number of times but the navigator doesn't appear

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the executables to your PATH.

Comment: OS? If windows, did you start the 'Anaconda prompt' instead of the default command line?

Comment: yes windows.. tried all options with path.still none conda commands recognized on command prompt

Comment: @Sonal But are you sure you started an 'Anaconda prompt'?